# Precision rounding error in Odoo 13 free edition

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I'm new to Odoo.
I have product with BOM that I manufacture from supplies in my inventory.
When I try to produce it, I get this error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1326, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\mrp\wizard\mrp_product_produce.py", line 97, in do_produce
    self._record_production()
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\mrp\wizard\mrp_product_produce.py", line 149, in _record_production
    self._update_finished_move()
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\mrp\models\mrp_abstract_workorder.py", line 273, in _update_finished_move
    float_round(self.qty_producing, precision_rounding=rounding)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\float_utils.py", line 55, in float_round
    precision_rounding=precision_rounding)
  File "E:\odoo\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\float_utils.py", line 30, in _float_check_precision
    "precision_rounding must be positive, got %s" % precision_rounding
AssertionError: precision_rounding must be positive, got 0.0
```

Does anybody have an idea how can I go about solving this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

**1 -** did you set decimal accuracy for the Product Unit of Measure digit to zero?
if yes, then that is the cause

**2 -** You might have a product where the reserved qty is 0.

Answer (score 1):

You probably used Stock as a scrap location. Or a stock move that was set to done with 0 in the initial demand.